# How can I put [] (square brackets) in RegExp javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying this:

```
str = "bla [bla]";
str = str.replace(/\\[\\]/g,"");
console.log(str);
```

And the replace doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: I'm trying to remove any square brackets in the string,
what's weird is that if I do

```
replace(/\[/g, '')
replace(/\]/g, '')
```

it works, but
 `replace(/\[\]/g, '');` 
doesn't.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It should be:

```
str = str.replace(/\[.*?\]/g,"");
```

You don't need double backslashes (\) because it's not a **string** but a regex statement, if you build the regex from a string you *do* need the double backslashes ;).

It was also literally interpreting the 1 (which wasn't matching).  Using `.*` says any value between the square brackets.

The new RegExp string build version would be:

```
str=str.replace(new RegExp("\\[.*?\\]","g"),"");
```

**UPDATE:** To remove square brackets only:

```
str = str.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g,"$1");
```

Your above code isn't working, because it's trying to match "[]" (sequentially without anything allowed between).  We can get around this by non-greedy group-matching (`(.*?)`) what's between the square brackets, and using a backreference (`$1`) for the replacement.

**UPDATE 2:** To remove multiple square brackets

```
str = str.replace(/\[+(.*?)\]+/g,"$1");
// bla [bla] [[blaa]] -> bla bla blaa
// bla [bla] [[[blaa] -> bla bla blaa
```

Note this doesn't match open/close quantities, simply removes all sequential opens and closes.  Also if the sequential brackets have separators (spaces etc) it won't match.

Comment: Your solution will not remove all brackets because of that greedy ".*" in there.  You don't need it anyway - just `str.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '')`

Comment: @Rudu this works if I have a single opening and closing brackets, what if I have `[[[`?

Answer (score 7):

You have to escape the bracket, like `\[` and `\]`. Check out http://regexpal.com/. It's pretty useful :)

To replace all brackets in a string, this should do the job:

```
str.replace(/\[|\]/g,'');
```

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: This works the best for me as there are multiple square brackets in my input string. Easy and generic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trivial example but worked for me. You have to escape each sq bracket, then enclose those brackets within a bracket expression to capture all instances.

```js
const stringWithBrackets = '[]]][[]]testing][[]][';
const stringWithReplacedBrackets = stringWithBrackets.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '');
console.log(stringWithReplacedBrackets);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was for removing all the square brackets from the string.

Comment: You're correct, sorry I missed the latest update from the OP. I will revise my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Two backslashes produces a single backslash, so you're searching for "a backslash, followed by a character class consisting of a `1` or a `right bracket`, and then you're missing an closing bracket.

Try

```
str.replace(/\[1\]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to match?

If you don't escape the brackets, they are considered character classes. This:

```
/[1\\]/
```

Matches either a 1 or a backslash. You may want to escape them with one backslash only:

```
/\[1\]/
```

But this won't match either, as you don't have a `[1]` in your string.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this question while dealing with *square bracket escaping within a character class* that was designed for use with password validation requiring the presence of special characters.

Note the double escaping:

> `var regex = new RegExp('[\\]]');`

As @rudu mentions, this expression *is* within a string so it must be double escaped. Note that the quoting type (single/double) is not relevant here.

Here is an example of using square brackets in a character class that tests for all the special characters found on *my* keyboard:

```
var regex = new RegExp('[-,_,\',",;,:,!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,(,),[,\\],\?,{,},|,+,=,<,>,~,`,\\\\,\,,\/,.]', 'g')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
str = "bla [bla]";

str.replace(/[[\\]]/g,'');
```

You create a character set with just the two characters you are interested in and do a global replace.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody quite made it simple and correct:

```
str.replace(/[[\]]/g, '');
```

Note the use of a character class, with no escape for the open bracket, and a single backslash escape for the close bracket.