# Replace all without a regex where can I use the G

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

So I have the following:

```
var token = '[token]';
var tokenValue = 'elephant';
var string = 'i have a beautiful [token] and i sold my [token]';
string = string.replace(token, tokenValue);
```

The above will only replace the first `[token]` and leave the second on alone.

If I were to use regex I could use it like

```
string = string.replace(/[token]/g, tokenValue);
```

And this would replace all my `[tokens]`

However I don't know how to do this without the use of `//`

Comment: why does `//` make a difference?

Comment: // are used in regex to define limiters. If there is a way to add the g or "all" to replace without it what is the way ?

Comment: The correct terminology for surrounding anything with `/ /` is that it makes a regex literal. The only ways I know of for doing replace all without a regex literal (or a third-party library) is to use the `RegExp` object constructor (which still uses a regex, see Isaac's answer), or to make a carefully constructed loop that will search for an occurrence of your `token` in the string and replace it with `tokenValue` until no occurrences of `token` are found. I suggest Isaac's answer if you are still able to use regex (not sure why you wouldn't be...).

Comment: The reason i cannot use his answer is: http://jsfiddle.net/U43uM/1/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not replace the token every time it appears with a do while loop?

```
var index = 0;
do {
    string = string.replace(token, tokenValue);
} while((index = string.indexOf(token, index + 1)) > -1);
```

Comment: Yours seems to be what i am looking for however doesnt indexOF has some browser incompatibility ?

Comment: You would have problems in older IE versions if you used [`Array.indexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679977(v=vs.94).aspx). However, [`String.indexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/53xtt423(v=vs.94).aspx) is supported, so you should have no problems using it on strings.

Comment: this will not work:

`var strinSample= 'CIC';

var index = 0;
do {
    strinSample = strinSample.replace('C', 'CC');
} while((index = strinSample.indexOf('C', index + 1)) > -1);`

Comment: Yes the problem is it searches from the beginning of the string every time.

Answer (score 20):

I have found split/join satisfactory enough for most of my cases.
A real-life example:

```
myText.split("\n").join('<br>');
```

Comment: what has this got to do with the question?

Comment: @Isaac is this closer to the question?

```
var token = '[token]';
var tokenValue = 'elephant';
var string = 'i have a beautiful [token] and i sold my [token]';
string = string.split(token).join(tokenValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string = string.replace(new RegExp("\\[token\\]","g"), tokenValue);
```

Comment: issac your answer is nice but does not solve my issue  and the "[]" are not being replaced - also i am unable to escape the "[]".

Comment: No cannot and even if i escape them there is still an issue.

Comment: After some fiddling, and looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863050/how-can-i-put-square-brackets-in-regexp-javascript I figured out how to escape `[]`

Comment: You're missing i am unable to escape or change the value of the variable token  Thanks for your help though

Comment: @NetaMeta Now it makes sense, you need to escape `[ ]` but can't change the original value of the `token` regex string. You could use the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) to replace characters in the `token` string with their equivalent regex metacharacters. Then you can use `token` as a regex where you please. Note that this would be a bad solution if a user inputs the regex, as they could put in something like `[`.

Answer (score 1):

Caution with the accepted answer, the replaceWith string can contain the inToReplace string, in which case there will be an infinite loop...

Here a better version:

```
function replaceSubstring(inSource, inToReplace, inReplaceWith)
{
    var outString = [];
    var repLen = inToReplace.length;

    while (true)
    {
        var idx = inSource.indexOf(inToReplace);
        if (idx == -1)
        {
            outString.push(inSource);
            break;
        }

        outString.push(inSource.substring(0, idx))
        outString.push(inReplaceWith);

        inSource = inSource.substring(idx + repLen);
    }

    return outString.join("");
}
```

Comment: In case you don't like putting `while(true)` in your code, here's a version with explicit condition: https://gist.github.com/naugtur/1d2227b09601e50dc9e0

Comment: It's much faster to append to a string than to make an array of parts and `.join("")` them. See my answer.

Comment: @Timmmm: To the best of my knowledge, that's not the case. I didn't measure this specific snippet, but usually, join is faster than concat. Did you actually measure it ? Which browser ? Which version ?

Comment: Yes I did. Chrome as of now. It's 4 times slower.

Comment: @Timmmm: Hmmm, used to be 100 times faster. But apparently, recent changes. Wondering about the performance of  var result = String.prototype.concat.apply("", arrayOfStrings);

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately since Javascript's string `replace()` function doesn't let you start from a particular index, and there is no way to do in-place modifications to strings it is really hard to do this as efficiently as you could in saner languages.

- `.split().join()` isn't a good solution because it involves the creation of a load of strings (although I suspect V8 does some dark magic to optimise this).
- Calling `replace()` in a loop is a terrible solution because replace starts its search from the beginning of the string every time. This is going to lead to O(N^2) behaviour! It also has issues with infinite loops as noted in the answers here.
- A regex is probably the best solution if your replacement string is a compile time constant, but if it isn't then you can't really use it. You should absolutely *not* try and convert an arbitrary string into a regex by escaping things.

One reasonable approach is to build up a new string with the appropriate replacements:

```
function replaceAll(input: string, from: string, to: string): string {
  const fromLen = from.length;
  let output = "";
  let pos = 0;
  for (;;) {
    let matchPos = input.indexOf(from, pos);
    if (matchPos === -1) {
      output += input.slice(pos);
      break;
    }
    output += input.slice(pos, matchPos);
    output += to;
    pos = matchPos + fromLen;
  }
  return output;
}
```

[I benchmarked this](https://jsbench.me/nyk6uj64k9/1) against all the other solutions (except calling `replace()` in a loop which is going to be terrible) and it came out slightly faster than a regex, and about twice as fast as `split`/`join`.

Edit: This is *almost* the same method as Stefan Steiger's answer which I totally missed for some reason. However his answer still uses `.join()` for some reason which makes it 4 times slower than mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
"[.token.*] nonsense and [.token.*] more nonsense".replace("[.token.*]", "some", "g");
```

Will produce:

"some nonsense and some more nonsense"

Comment: Please note that this only works on [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: The flags parameter has been removed from Firefox now so this doesn't work anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the answer from @TheBestGuest won't work for the following example as you will end up in an endless loop:

```
var stringSample= 'CIC'; 
var index = 0; 
do { stringSample = stringSample.replace('C', 'CC'); } 
while((index = stringSample.indexOf('C', index + 1)) > -1);
```

So here is my proposition for replaceAll method written in TypeScript:

```js
let matchString = 'CIC';
let searchValueString= 'C';
let replacementString ='CC';
    
matchString = matchString.split(searchValueString).join(replacementString);
     console.log(matchString);
```