# node.js url with square bracket

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In express.js i am trying to add a router for url **/xxx/xxx/items[5]** .
the url have Square Bracket.

Router works fine without Square Bracket, but fails with Square Bracket.

Have any one faced this before if so, what is the way to make it work.

```
var buildingDeviceCount = require("../models/buildingDeviceCount");
/* api/analytics/v1/deviceCount/Building[5]/today?areas=&yAxis=absoluteDevices&timeRange=00:00-23:59 */
router.get('/api/analytics/v1/deviceCount/Building[5]/today', function(req, res) {
res.json(buildingDeviceCount.buildingDeviceCount);
});
```

Comment: share some code please, let us see if you have tried anything, like escaping or double quoting it...

Comment: You could edit your original post with that code so it is easier to read...

Comment: added code in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're passing a string to a regex function in JS you need to escape the backslash before the opening bracket, like so

```
router.get('/api/analytics/v1/deviceCount/Building\\[5\]/today', function(req, res) {
```

Related:
[How can I put [] (square brackets) in RegExp javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863050/how-can-i-put-square-brackets-in-regexp-javascript)

Also, use this to get the number in the brackets

```
app.get('/api/analytics/v1/deviceCount/Building\\[:n\]/today', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params.n)
});
```

Comment: Is that always? What if you use a reg-ex-y string instead? `/\/api.../` etc?

Comment: Apparently it's only when passing a string to be built into a regex. Using an actual regex it should work with only one backslash. Haven't tested it though.

Comment: Not directly related, but you might want to consider using express's pattern matching ability to extract the number in the brackets. I'll add that in the answer just for future reference.

Comment: I've sent a [pull request](https://github.com/component/path-to-regexp/pull/25) to fix this. There was already a list of special regexp characters that were being escaped, but the brackets were not in that list.

Comment: above code Works fine in chrome but breaks in FF. Data is not getting fetched. any one know what will be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the square bracket `[` and `]` chars are causing chaos is due to the fact that they represent the basic [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) in Regular Expressions. Additionally, express.js allows its routes to be defined with regular expressions in them. So, here is what you are actually telling express to respond to when you say: `/xxx/xxx/items[5]` it is trying to match the given URL with `/xxx/xxx/items5`

To fix it, define your route like this:

```
app.get(/^\/api\/analytics\/v1\/deviceCount\/Building\[\d+\]\/today/, function(req, res) {...});
```

**EDIT:**

I just found out that express allows for parameter validation. So you can try something like this as well...

```
app.param("building_5", /^Building\[\d+\]$/);
app.get("/api/analytics/v1/deviceCount/:building_5/today", function(req, res) {...});
```

Comment: are you always expecting the N in `Building[N]` to be 5?

Comment: What error / message are you seeing? Do you catch the 404 server-side?

Comment: after adding the param, i am getting following error `code` Error: invalid param() call for building_5, got /^Building\[5\]$/