# Javascript string replace short tags with brackets

Tags: javascript, string, replace

https://jsfiddle.net/jt8mLhk0/1/

I try to string replace something wrapped into brackets with something else. I get really weird results.

**Html/js**

```js
var string = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
var replace = string.replace(/[prefix]/g, "replaced");
console.log(replace); // Look in developer tools console
```

```html
<div id="test">A little [prefix] test</div>
```

**Original string**

> A little [prefix] test

**Expected (what I was hoping for)**

> A little replaced test

**Results**

> A lreplacedttlreplaced [replacedreplacedreplacedreplacedreplacedreplaced] treplacedst

I also want to replace multiple matches, that's why I use `/g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the `[]` in regex pattern .
square brackets have important role in regex .see what [`How can I put \[\] (square brackets) in RegExp javascript?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863050/how-can-i-put-square-brackets-in-regexp-javascript)

```js
var string = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
var replace = string.replace(/\[prefix\]/g, "replaced");
console.log(replace); // Look in developer tools console
```

```html
<div id="test">A little [prefix] test</div>
```

Comment: In your example you escape both of the brackets. In another example only one is escaped. Both seems to work. Should the last bracket be escaped or not?

Comment: In this case single escape only enough..for some other case .Better ecape with both @JensTörnell

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `[`.

```js
var string = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
var replace = string.replace(/\[prefix]/g, "Replaced");
console.log(replace); // Look in developer tools console
```

```html
<div id="test">A little [prefix] test [prefix]</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use this

```
string.replace(/\[prefix]/g, "Replaced");
```

Answer (score 1):

In the regular expression, you just have to add a '\' before each square bracket like this:

```
<div id="test">A little [prefix] test</div>

<script>
  var string = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML;
  var replace = string.replace(/\[prefix\]/g, "Replaced");
  console.log(replace); // Look in developer tools console
</script>
```