# Javascript replace function using regex with multiple matching strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this following String below

`[01]ABC0007[0d0a]BB BABLOXC[0d0a]067989 PLPXBNS[0d0a02]BBR OIC002 L5U0/P AMD KAP 041800 T1200AND 2+00[0d0a0b03]`

And I am attempting to replace all `[..]` with spaces.

What I have tried.

```
return this.text.replace(new RegExp('[0d0a] | [0d0a02] | [0d0a02]' ) ,  ' ')
return this.text.replace(new RegExp('\[0d0a\] | \[0d0a02\] | \[0d0a02\]' ) ,  ' ')
```

What works is only this.

```
return this.text.replace(new RegExp('0d0a') ,  ' ')
```

Posts in this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings) involve multiple steps. This is going to be used as input as 'javascript' string to the *Bson* filter for **mongo** queries since mongo does not yet have **REPLACE** function like SQL has. There is a [open](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-829) request.

Comment: `[` and `]` both have special meaning in regexp.

Comment: \ has special meaning in javascript strings.

Comment: Have you tried this as your RegExp to match against?:  //[.*//]

Comment: For info on including square brackets: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6863050/2125723

Comment: No, none of the above worked. The only thing which worked was chaining replace(). There in another variable here since the javascript is passed to the mongo engine for processing. It is not the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your brackets: `\[\]`. Also, you can check for anything between the brackets (non-greedy): `\[.*?\]`:

```js
let string = `[01]ABC0007[0d0a]BB BABLOXC[0d0a]067989 PLPXBNS[0d0a02]BBR OIC002 L5U0/P AMD KAP 041800 T1200AND 2+00[0d0a0b03]`;

let replaced = string.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, ' ');

console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the opening bracket `\[` if you want to match for example `[0d0a]`. In your second regex you have to remove the whitespace before and after the `|` because it has meaning.

Your regex would look like:

[`\[0d0a]|\[0d0a02]|\[0d0a02]`](https://regex101.com/r/qItTlB/1)

```js
let str = "[01]ABC0007[0d0a]BB BABLOXC[0d0a]067989 PLPXBNS[0d0a02]BBR OIC002 L5U0/P AMD KAP 041800 T1200AND 2+00[0d0a0b03]";
console.log(str.replace(/\[0d0a]|\[0d0a02]|\[0d0a02]/g, ' '));
```

If you want to match all from opening till closing bracket you could use:

[`\[[^\]]+]`](https://regex101.com/r/abj7VO/1)

That would match from `[` till `]` and matches what is between using a negated character class `[^[]+` which will match not a `]` one or more times.

```js
let str = "[01]ABC0007[0d0a]BB BABLOXC[0d0a]067989 PLPXBNS[0d0a02]BBR OIC002 L5U0/P AMD KAP 041800 T1200AND 2+00[0d0a0b03]";
console.log(str.replace(/\[[^\]]+]/g, ' '));
```