# Mongodb '$where' query using javascript regex

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to reproduce the REPLACE function in sql on mongodb.

My collection '**log**' has this data in the '**text**' field.

```
[01]ABC0007[0d0a]BB BABLOXC[0d0a]067989 PLPXBNS[0d0a02]BBR OIC002 L5U0/P AMD KAP 041800 T1200AND 2+00[0d0a0b03]
```

All I'm trying to do is remove the '[..]' using regex (javascript) and use contains('PLPXBNSBBR') like this so that the expression return true per the [javadocs](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html#where-java.lang.String-) in mongo documentation.

This query below successfully works and returns the matching rows.

> db.log.find({"$where":"return this.message.replace(new RegExp('0d0a02'),'').contains('PLPXBNS[]BBR') "});

However, I would need to remove the '[..]' and match like this PLPXBNSBBR.

These are the ones I tried unsuccessfully

> db.log.find({"$where" : "  return this.message.replace(  new
>   RegExp('\[.*?\]', 'g'), ''  ).contains('PLPXBNSBBR')  "  });
>
> db.log.find({"$where" : "  return this.message.replace(  new
>   RegExp('/[(.*?)]', 'g'), ''  ).contains('PLPXBNSBBR')  "  });
>
> db.log.find({"$where" : "  return this.message.replace(  new
>   RegExp('//[.*//]'), ''  ).contains('PLPXBNSBBR')  "  });
>
> db.log.find({"$where" : "  return this.message.replace(  new
>   RegExp('[.*?]'), ''  ).contains('PLPXBNSBBR')  "  });

From the earlier [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50977436/4904) it appears that if I can pass the pattern as /[[^]]+]/g, it should strip the [..] but it is not doing that and not returning the matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to use chaining replace successfully to get my desired results.